# Finding an opportunity in a Canadian company without having the permenant recidency

Tags: immigration, canada, job-hunting

I finished my PhD from a European country recently and I got an offer to do a postdoc (working contract) in a Canadian university for 1 year (can be extended two).

I just heard that if my postdoc contract finished before I got the PR, I can't work in other companies. I should have PR to work in a company in Canada.

Is this right?

Comment: In general, you need either Canadian citizenship, permanent residency, or a valid work permit to work in Canada, with limited exceptions for specific situations. You can however look for work and see if the employer will sponsor a work permit or if your nationality and situation allow for other work permit routes.

Comment: @zhantongz thanks for your clarification. But is possible then to apply for a open-work permit?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, a company would have to initiate the application for a work permit.

Comment: @mkennedy .. of course, but is it possible or the priority should be always given to the citizens and PR holders?

Comment: @user_007 It depends on your nationality and the exact nature of your postdoc. It is much better to ask the school's employment or international support office for details. In principle employers will prefer people who they do not need to sponsor (citizens, PRs, open work permit holders).